# Can not resolve domain name of few sites in new country

Tags: dns, isp

I used to visit a few sites in different country.
But now i have travelled to my home country and saw that domain name is not resolving.

However if I use IP address then I can see the website.

How can I correct the problem?

Do I have to call my ISP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your DNS servers to a publicly available one. Here's a list of [Publicly Available DNS Servers](http://theos.in/windows-xp/free-fast-public-dns-server-list/).

Comment: @Moorage  If it worked, you should click on the tick mark next to the question! It will mark it as solved and give credit to person who posted it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using google's dns - 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

For a test, you can execute the following command

## nslookup

> server 8.8.8.8
>
> facebook.com

Answer (score 0):

Which country?  Does your government require ISPs to filter out certain domain-names?

If so, do the DNS outside your country (VPN systems, etc).